# F12 for wifi not working on HP M6-1045DX

Tags: wireless, hp, intel, centrino

I've searched for hours and tried multiple suggestions to no avail, except for
editing `iwlwifi.conf` and adding the "extra options", I'm not sure doing that part applies to my setup or not.

OK, here's what I have:

result of `lspci -v`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at 50500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 68:5d:43:d6:e2:9b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.3-031603-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:50500000-50501fff
```

result of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

and `rfkill unblock all` seems to do nothing.

Update: booting into Windows and enabling it there does the trick but this doesn't 
seem like a permanent solution for the underlying cause.